# Checking that a string with multiple lines only contains a set of specific characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to validate that a string that might contain more than one line will only contain the next characters:
whitespace, underscore or a pipe (" ", "_" "|")

I did this:

```
string =~ /^[\ \|\_]+$/
```

And it's working fine if the string only has one line like for example:

```
"|_| _| _ |_ |_| a _" =~ /^[\ \|\_]+$/ # false
```

But in this case, it will return true, and I don't want that

```
"|_| _| _ |_ |_|\n 14sdfsdf" =~ /^[\ \|\_]+$/ # true?
```

In other languages, I can add the "global" flag, but I don't know how to do it in Ruby.

I need it to return a boolean.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the the `\A` and `\z` anchors to match the beginning and end of the string, respectively:

```
"|_| _| _ |_ |_|\n 14sdfsdf" =~ /\A[ |_\n]+\z/
# => nil
```

Note that I've also added `\n` to the character class, and removed the escapes that aren't necessary inside a character class.

See it on Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/qR4eVaOVof or repl.it: https://repl.it/I0IR

If you're using Ruby 2.4+, instead of `=~` you can use the [`String#match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-match-3F) method (note the question mark), which returns a boolean (and doesn't populate the `$~`, `$1`, etc. globals, making it *very slightly* more efficient):

```
"|_| _| _ |_ |_|\n 14sdfsdf".match?(/\A[ |_\n]+\z/)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! i just added `!!()` around it and it returns a bool too

Comment: @SamuelE. I'm not sure if you saw my edit, but the `m` flag isn't necessary after all. Also, if you're using Ruby 2.4+, instead of `=~` you can use the [`String#match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-match-3F) method, which returns a boolean (and is also *slightly* more efficient for reasons mentioned in the linked docs).

Comment: `nil` is a boolean?

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, it's not. Perhaps you're thinking of `String#match`.

Comment: What I meant was that the OP asked that it return a boolean (`true` or `false`), but you return `nil`. Perhaps the OP did the edit after you answered.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Imagine that. Looks like OP figured it out anyway.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I don't use the `m` flag and Im running ruby version 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has the `.scan` method for Strings which can allow you to scan through the whole String as needed, and call the regex statement on this as well.

This scans in each section to an array allowing you to check each index.

See here: https://apidock.com/ruby/String/scan

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, but I forgot to say that I need it to return a boolean

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's easier to check whether the string contains a character other than the given ones:

```
r = /[^\s_|]/

"|_| _| _ |_ |_|\n _" !~ r                #=> true
"|_| _| _ |_ |_|\n 14sdfsdf" !~ /[^\s_|]/ #=> false
```

Anchors are not needed and `!~` returns a Boolean.